# Displaying string with format in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a credit card number field on a table.
For <%= f.text_field :credit_number %>, I want to show it with some format like 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx' instead of 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
But I don't want to save the space with the number in the DB.

For now I don't care about inputting but only displaying.

What's the best way to accomplish it?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text_field` not good for credit card number use `<input type="number">` instead.Try create helper, for render in view like this:

```
=> "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".chars.each_slice(4).map(&:join)*' '
=> "xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx"
```

in view use placeholder:

```
<%= f.text_field :credit_number, placeholder: "xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" %>
```

From comment:

add before_create block to model in `models/user.rb`:

```
before_create do
  credit_number.split(' ').join if credit_number
end
```

Now before create (write to db) `credit_number` string join.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, you misunderstood my question. I know how to change the string. But I want to save the data without format while showing with format.

Comment: @SamKong add `before_create` block to you model. Look update answer